# Keys getting swapped round in KDE

Tags: keyboard, kde

After I run `mplayer`, the cursor keys on my keyboard get swapped with random keys on my keyboard...

```
Up = Print
Left = ISO_Level3_Shift
Right = Windows key
Down = Nothing
```

Restarting seems to fix the problem. The only sort-of work around I have is to turn off KHotkey daemon (which stops KSnapshot starting every time I press `up`). Changing the keyboard layout from one to another doesn't do anything, and also changing the keyboard model seems to have no effect. All other keys seem to work fine. I've never seen anything like this before.

What could I try?

### Update:

Ah, actually it's not be mplayer. It's prooving to be very difficult to figure out exactly what is causing this to happen. It's fine when I first log in, but at some point the key swap occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have some key redefining going on in your MPlayer settings? Move `~/.mplayer/` away and try again.

Here's a work-around that aids you in debugging. Save your current working X keyboard layout to a file: `setxkbmap -print | xkbcomp -xkb - -o ~/unborked.xkb`
Restore it any time: `xkbcomp - $DISPLAY < ~/unborked.xkb`

Comment: Cool, I'll give that a try.